# Limiting text read by VoiceOver from a UILabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, voiceover

I'm creating an app similar to Mail (or Messages or Notes) that displays `UITableViewCell`s that contain a message preview. The text usually doesn't all fit in the `UILabel`, so the text is truncated and an ellipsis is displayed automatically. This works well in my app for sighted users, however when using VoiceOver the entire `text` content of the `UILabel` is read aloud. That does not occur in Mail - VoiceOver stops announcing text upon reaching the ellipsis.

How can I obtain the same behavior in my app as Mail - enforce VoiceOver stop announcing text when it reaches the ellipsis?

`cell.messagePreviewLabel.text = a_potentially_really_long_string_here`

Comment: For voice over pass the text which fits the label. Using the label width, height and font family extract the text that actually fits in it and pass it to voice over

Comment: It would be a really useful feature if Apple supported it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subclass of UILabel that will do what you want.  Note, I have gone to zero effort to optimize this.  That part is up to you.  My overall recommendation, from an accessibility point of view, would still be to simply leave it.  Overriding an accessibility label to only portray a portion of the text in the actual label is a really questionable thing to do from an A11y perspective.  Use this tool very carefully!

```
@interface CMPreivewLabel : UILabel
@end

@implementation CMPreviewLabel

- (NSString*)accessibilityLabel {
    return [self stringThatFits];
}

- (NSString*)stringThatFits {
    if (self.numberOfLines != 1) return @"This class would need modifications to support more than one line previews";

    const int width = self.bounds.size.width;

    NSMutableAttributedString* resultString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];

    while (width < resultString.size.width) {
        NSRange range = [resultString.string rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];

        range.length = resultString.length - range.location;

        [resultString.mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    }

    return resultString.string;
}

@end
```